# Threading with a for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to create a for loop from 0 to 4 but my problem is I know only how to initiate one thread each time like this.

```
thread t1(eat,"hello");
thread t2(eat,"hello");
```

So my question is how can I initiate many thread at a time in a loop ?

Comment: Instantiate `std::thread` in dynamic scope, using the `new` keyword. Or, declare an array outside of the loop.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please

Comment: @StoryTeller - `detach` is not the solution to confusion about how to create multiple threads. Its purpose is to create threads with unbounded lifetimes, and it's only appropriate when that is the design goal Note that the accepted answer (yours <g>) doesn't do `join` or `detach`, and that's appropriate in answering this question.

Comment: @PeteBecker- I posted the above as a comment (and the better approach as an answer), precisely because I wasn't sure of the OP's ultimate goal. I just felt I'd be remiss if I didn't mention it *at all*. Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to just build them in-place in a vector<sup>1</sup>:

```
std::vector<std::thread> ts;

for (int i = 5; i > 0; --i)
  ts.emplace_back(eat, "hello");
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Reserving](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the memory in advance (assuming you know how much) can also be good.